# How to configure auto-loading for a library that doesn't specify auto-loading in composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

If a library downloaded via composer doesn't specify auto-loading, is there a way to specify in our composer.json file to be able to modify the library's auto-loading settings, without having to fork the library?

One approach I had thought of was to just patch the library's composer.json file, but https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches doesn't support editing the composer.json files.

Comment: If this were me, depending on what type of project I was working on, I'd just use `spl_autoload_register`, use either an array or class-to-file-system lookup (depending on library size, complexity, patterns and likelihood of change) and include that right around my standard `vendor/autoload.php` include. If this project is old and not maintained, I'd also consider forking it just to keep control of things. But I've found that although messing with composer's pipeline is totally possible, it usually isn't worth the effort unless you need to scale this to a bunch of unrelated projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can include autoloading information for the vendor library in your `composer.json`, without the need for patching the lib. For example:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "SomeNamespace\\SomeName\\": "vendor/some-namespace/some-name/src/"
    }
},
```

This will work, however, you need to make sure that you use the proper autoloading standard (PSR-0 vs PSR-4 vs classmap vs files) that matches the file structure of the library in question.

A better solution would be to create a pull request to the library author to add the autoloading information to the library itself.